# order function only partially reordering dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have created a data frame using `rbind()` to append two data frames with the same row names together. I am then trying to use the `order()` function to order the factor levels alphabetically. However, it is still treating the data frames as two separate objects, and ordering the first alphabetically, and then the second alphabetically separately.

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(site=c("A", "F", "C"))

df2 <- data.frame(site=c("B", "G", "D"))

new.df <- rbind(df1, df2)

new.df <- new.df[order(new.df$site),]
```

outcome:

```
site
A
C
F
B
D
G
```

I have looked at other methods of reordering data, for example using the `arrange` function from package `dplyr`, but have not had any success. Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid creation of factors by

```
df1 <- data.frame(site=c("A", "F", "C"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(site=c("B", "G", "D"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

then the remaining stuff will work as expected.

Comment: @M.Hilton I'm glad you find my answer useful. Would you mind to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left side? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not doing quite what you think you're doing there: the resulting new.df isn't a data frame any more, it's a factor. The result of `order` is to put it in the order of the levels of the factor (see `levels(new.df$site)`. So, if you really want to do it this way (ie, keeping it as a factor rather than a character vector), you will need to reorder the levels first.

```
new.df$site <- factor(new.df$site, levels = sort(levels(new.df$site)))
new.df[order(new.df$site), ]
[1] A B C D F G
Levels: A B C D F G
```

But unless you really need it to be a factor from the start, I think you would be best advised to do what @Uwe Block suggests and, if necessary, turn it in to a factor after you've used `rbind` and done the sorting.